# Xbox 360 freezing and not turning on

Tags: xbox-360

My Xbox 360 has been freezing regularly whether I'm playing GTA or FIFA. Today when I was playing it froze, so I tried to restart the console, and it gave me 3 red rings.

So, I unplugged everything because this has worked in the past.

When I restarted it, the light was green, but, the console wouldn't turn on.

So, next, I opened the disc tray, and it froze giving me 1 red ring.  Now it gives me no rings and it just doesn't start up.

I am going to leave it unplugged over night and see if it helps. But, does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: It's dead, Jim.

Comment: Red ring of death. It's not worth fixing. Just get a new one. They've become fairly cheap at least where I live after the launch of Xbox One.

Comment: Befure buying new one check the warranty though. Dunno how things are now but couple of years ago you could change Xbox360 with RROD for free even if it was 3 years old (maybe even up to 5 but not sure). That\`s how I changed my old white one for new slim anyways =)

Comment: "The light was green but the console wouldn't turn on" --> I had this problem the other day on mine, apparently the hard drive had got knocked loose somehow. Once I snapped it back into place it worked fine.

Comment: Vaccuum the console and power brick while it's all unplugged, off, and no disk in the tray. Then try turning it on using the eject button, leaving the tray open(less work for the Xbox). No usb, no HDD, no network(cable or wireless).

Comment: I used to have Xbox360 and came across this problem twice! The only way I fixed this was through warranty the first time and when the second time this happened I realized the only way to fix this is to drop Microsoft's crappy excuse for a gaming console and go with PS. After which, I never looked back nor had a problem with consoles.

Comment: @ryekayo Haha! Thats the spirit! *cheap smile*

Answer (score 0):

If you're under warranty, MS will fix it for free.  Although inconvenient, it's a quick and streamlined service.

Failing that, you should be able to pick up a 2nd hand 360 for £50 or so.  There's one on eBay for £46 as I type this.

Oh, and bad luck.  I've had a few RRODs and it's a royal pain in the rump.

Comment: On that note... Sending a White console to Microsoft, may mean for the repair fee(Around 135-200 AU$) generally they may replace it with a Slim like Icebat had stated. A neighbour did that last year with one of my old RROD, and seems they replaced it with a new White(though I think he may have requested to keep it. Also a work collegue did the same, and yes replaced.